# How do I install moodle with the CodeRunner module on openshift?

Tags: python, openshift, moodle

I have installed moodle on openshift using the instructions on https://github.com/burningTyger/openshift_moodle though I confess to not really understanding the details of how it works.

I now want to install the CodeRunner https://github.com/trampgeek/CodeRunner moodle question type on openshift so I can write python programming questions on moodle. I have no idea where to even start. I'm not even sure if it's possible.

I know python well, but am new to openshift, and moodle admin.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with Moodle or CodeRunner so someone from those communities might be able to provide a better answer but, OpenShift is quite versatile and can run lots of different application types. The best way for you to find out if it works is do the following:

1. ssh into your gear with `rhc ssh <yourappname>`
2. cd into your data directoy  `cd ~/app-root/data`
3. clone the CodeRunner repo
4. Run through the install instructions listed in that repo.

Note: I took a look at the instructions and it says to disable SELinux which you won't be able to do so I'm not sure how it will affect the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the CodeRunner developer, but I know nothing about OpenShift. However, I'm not optimistic about your chances. What sandbox were you planning on using? The built-in RunGuard sandbox is normally the easiest option but SELinux will probably get in the way, because it won't allow the webserver to exec the Python interpreter or C compiler etc. I think you would need to install the [Jobe sandbox](https://github.com/trampgeek/jobe) on OpenShift as well. CodeRunner would then need to be able to connect to Jobe to run the submitted jobs. The necessary language compilers and interpreters for whatever question types you want to use would need to be installed too, in the same VM/container/whatever as Jobe. Jobe and Moodle can co-exist on the same VM, but whether that's a good way to go with OpenShift, or even if it's feasible, I don't know.

Comment: Yes, it would be the Jobe sandbox on OpenShift. But in parallel with the longer-term effort of getting the whole thing working on OpenShift, I've been getting shorter term experience (as you know...) with moodle and CodeRunner with the runguard interface. I figure I can always transfer course material from one to the other. I really appreciate your willingness to help out...

Comment: FWIW, I have built a working Moodle + CodeRunner on OpenShift. I started with BurningTyger (https://github.com/burningTyger/openshift_moodle), cloned CodeRunner into ~/app-root/data. Then:

Comment: Grrr ... timed me out. As I was saying, I then unzipped the question type and behaviour zips  (install instructions, method 1) into the appropriate Moodle folders. That worked out of the box EXCEPT it's using the default sandbox which is a jobe server at the University of Canterbury, set up for testing only. It is limited to 100 jobs per hour over all users anywhere in the world, so if you want a real system you'll have to set up your own Jobe server.